# create separate page template for wordpress comments

Tags: comments

I would like to know how to create separate page for comments with pagination ?

like archive page or index page

IE: someone is on my blog and wants to see all comments

e.g. http://www.wplover.com/comments-central

Answer (score 1):

That appears to be simply a Page template that outputs the "Recent Comments" Widget for comments and pings, and then (probably) another Widget that displays a list of most-commented Posts.

If those indeed are Widgets, then you simply need to create a custom Page template, and instead of outputting a Loop, output a [`the_widget()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_widget) call for each Widget you want to display. e.g. do something like: